# Problems setting up Azure in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to follow the directions here: [Azure Resource Manager Cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt125356.aspx)

I do this:

```
PS C:\> Install-Module AzureRM
```

That works, then I try this:

```
PS C:\> Install-AzureRM
```

I get this message:

> Install-AzureRM : The term 'Install-AzureRM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Install-Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn807162.aspx) in article you came across is referring to cmdlet come with [WMF5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395). In other words, only available in Powershell 5.0

There is another version of Install-Module come with PsGet, but that one won't accomplish your task (Install-Module AzureRM), so please try to avoid it.

If you don't want to install powershell 5.0, but want azure cmdlet, you can find [stand-alone module installer here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to use Import-AzureRM instead of Install-AzureRM

Comment: `The term 'Import-AzureRM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`